# codeigniter extra url segments

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am making a site for a client and decided i would use code igniter.

The site essentially has two backends, one for designers, and one for a sales team. So after logging in, the user will be redirected to either

- mysite.com/sales/
- mysite.com/design/

The sales team for example can view orders, containers, products, therefore i need a controller for each of these.

- mysite.com/sales/orders/

The sales need to be able to view, edit, delete certain orders...

- mysite.com/sales/orders/vieworder/235433

Basically my problem is i dont have enough url segments to play with.

My thoughts on solving my problem

- removing the orders, containers, products classes and making ALL of their methods as methods of the sales class, although this would mean a large number of methods and loading all models so it seemed kind of pointless.
- removing the sales/designer classes and controlling what each kind of user has access to based on a user type stored in session data.
- a way of having an extra url segment?

I appreciate any advice, I just dont want to get 3 weeks into the project and realise i started wrong from the beginning!

Comment: Pardon me, "how" exactly are you missing "extra url segments"?
What is "missing"?

Comment: hi. youve quoted me as saying "missing" although i didnt? I just need a way of allowing a sales team to access certain classes and their methods, and allowing designers to access some of the same classes but not all of their methods.

Comment: Why not users some kind of access right via DB, and prevent the function from executing if the user/designer is missing the privilege?

Comment: That was one of my thoughts, although i was just unsure if that would be the best way to do it. Is that the best way then?

Comment: Sure it is, how are you supposed to do it different, without maximizing your effort? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use folders.

If you make a subfolder in `/application/` called `sales` you can put different controllers in there:

```
/application/
    /sales/
      orders.php /* Controller */
    /design/
```

Then in `orders.php` you will put your `vieworders($id)` method and so on, and you will be able to acces it with `domain.com/sales/orders/vieworders/id`.

You can also make subfolders in the `/models/` and `/views/` to organize your files.

Now, Access Control is something apart and it depends more in the auth system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Give the user/designer a privilege, a column in the user table for example, check the permission of the user at the beginning of the function, then prevent or execute it.

This would be the exact way i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should have a look into the routing class. Might be a dirty solution but rerouting the sales/(:any) to something like sales_$1 would mean you'd make controllers with names like sales_orders.
Same for the design part.

(FYI: `$routing['sales/(:any)'] = 'sales_$1';` should do the trick; see application/config/routing.php).